# Accessing String inside Object inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, object, chaining

In wordpress I have a data structure like this:

```
array
  49 => 
    object(stdClass)[272]
      public 'ID' => int 49
      ...
      // I need this guid
      public 'guid' => string 'http://localhost/github/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/3.png' (length=66)
      ...
  47 => 
    object(stdClass)[275]

  46 => 
    object(stdClass)[276]
      public 'ID' => int 46
      ...
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

I'm trying to access the `guid` and this works:

```
$temp121212 = get_children($post->ID);
echo $temp121212[49]->guid;
```

But this doesn't :

```
echo get_children($post->ID)[49]->guid;
```

What am I doing wrong? Can this not be done like this?

Answer (score 0):

Up to php 5.3, you can't [as you would do in javascript, for example] - that's called array dereferencing.

So you have to store your array somewhere:

```
$child = get_children($post->ID)[49];
echo $child -> guid;
```

In php 5.4 however you are allowed to use your syntax.